# How set all posts in wordpress in one category

Tags: categories

I Have 9587 Posts that in 2 category.

I need to delete one category and set it in one category, For-example, I have post in (News, Hot News) categories.

So i need this post in one category (News).

How can do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is by way of this excellent plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/term-management-tools/

Once installed it will allow you to consolidate categories just as you wish.